# How to get Interent speed in android?

Tags: android

I am using SOAP Parser in my programme.But some time is Internet very slow.So i need to check the internet speed . Please can give me some code. Even i was use 2G and 3G and wifi also.

Answer (score 2):

2G/3G

To determine network type use:

```
TelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
```

e.g.

```
bool is3G = (manager.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS);
```

Docs for the class can be found at: [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)